# Are origin characters silent in multiplayer?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

One common complaint is that, when playing an origin character as your main character, they are mostly silent, throughout the game, meaning you miss out on a lot of that characters dialog, banter, backstory etc.

**Is this true with multiple origin characters in multiplayer as well?** For instance, if all four players are playing origin characters, will all four characters be silent during dialog, or will the three who aren't controlling the dialog react like they would as extra party members in single-player?